# odd sized structure with bitfields

Tags: c, struct, padding, bit-fields, packed

I am trying to fit a few bitfields into a 3-byte struct

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct  _DSTEntry {
    uint8_t reserved :6;
    uint8_t startMonth:4;
    uint8_t startDay:5;
    uint8_t endMonth:4;
    uint8_t endDay:5;
} __attribute__((packed)) DSTEntry;
#pragma pop
```

However, sizeof DSTEntry is always 5, allthough the sum of all bits is 24. 
I am using gcc 5.3.0.

Comment: Solution: don't use bit-fields in the first place. They are broken by language design.

Comment: If you use `uint16_t` instead of `uint8_t` then the size will go down to 4. I think you have no chance of getting it down to 3 though.

Comment: Can't reproduce.

Comment: Some compiler implementations (most?) won't split a bitfield across a 8-bit (uint8_t) or 16-bit (uint16_t) boundary.  So `reserved` takes 6 bits, leaving only 2.  However `startMonth` requires 4 bits.  The compiler will not divide 'startMonth' between the last two bits of the first byte, and the first two bits of the next byte.  As @PaulR states, you won't be able to get this down to 3.

Comment: I have to update my earlier comment above - gcc 5.4.0 gives the required size of 3, and doesn't seem to care whether you use `uint8_t` or `uint16_t` - I'm quite surprised by this, and obviously it's not portable or advisable (e.g. MSVC gives 4 or 5, depending on which type you use).

Answer (score 0):

If you have the freedom to rearrange the elements in the structure, you can try this:

```
typedef struct  _DSTEntry {
    uint16_t reserved :6;
    uint16_t startDay:5;
    uint16_t endDay:5;
    uint8_t startMonth:4;
    uint8_t endMonth:4;
} __attribute__((packed)) DSTEntry;
```

This resulted in size 3 for me, with gcc 4.9.2.  If the fields must remain in that order, then I think the best you can do is four bytes with:

```
typedef struct  _DSTEntry {
    uint16_t reserved :6;
    uint16_t startDay:5;
    uint16_t startMonth:4;
    uint8_t endDay:5;
    uint8_t endMonth:4;
} __attribute__((packed)) DSTEntry;
```